# How to output value of a two dimensional array to a text area?

Tags: javascript, webforms, multidimensional-array

I can access the first dimension of the two-dimensional array but how would I access the second one? I want to display values of the array in a text-area in a table like way using escape sequences like \t and \n.

My source so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var txt = "";
                var Person = new Array(4);
                for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
                    Person[i] = new Array(5);
                function display()
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i< 4; i++)
                        {
                            txt += "Person " + i + \t;
                            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                                txt += Person[i][j] + \t;
                            txt += \n;
                        }
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = txt;
                    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="display()" /><br />
                <textarea id="results" rows="7" cols="39"></textarea>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn’t be easier: replace

```
<!-- stuck here -->
```

by

```
Person[i][j];
```

You've made `Person` an array of arrays.  With `Person[i]`, you’ve got its `i`th element, which is an array.  With `Person[i][j]`, you’ve got the `j`th element of that inner array.

You could also write it like this:

```
var array = Person[i];
innerHTML += array[j];
```

As a side note, I’d assemble your text before assigning it to the innerHTML property, it’s a lot faster: the way you’ve written it now means looking up the textarea each time, fetching its innerHTML, adding our bit to it, and reassigning it to the innerHTML property.

Comment: For some reason it won't display anything in the textarea when I click Submit. I've edited the source and posted it in the OP to put all the data into a variable and then assign its contents to the textarea.

Comment: Perhaps it’s because you’ve put the code on the 'submit' button?  You click 'submit', your code gets executed **while the page is being refreshed**... which means the page is destroyed before your loop even stops running.  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wccUE/